# Is there any branch of the Protestant Church that can receive Communion at Mass?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, communion, mass

Does Roman Catholicism allow certain Protestants to receive communion during the mass if they have been baptized and confirmed?  I'd like to know if there are any Protestant denominations that Roman Catholicism would "accept" for this purpose, such as the Episcopal Church.  Does it matter if the Protestant believes Catholic doctrine regarding the nature of the Eucharist?

Or do all Protestants have to convert to Catholicism in order to be able to be permitted to participate in the mass?

Comment: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/653/as-a-protestant-may-i-participate-in-the-eucharist-communion-when-visiting-a/6625?s=11|0.0727#6625 might be considered a duplicate of this question. Short version: You should ask; probably not. Clearly this is important to you, as you're more than a visitor. If you still have contact with leaders at the Episcopalian church, you might want to discuss it with them also. This site avoids giving specific pastoral advice because experts here differ widely in their personal beliefs.

Comment: Please merge this with the duplicate because the answer below is better than most or all of the answers on the original.